# Automatically launch a command with Emacs when it's a .tex file

Tags: emacs, latex, emacs23

I want to launch a command when I start `emacs` with a `.tex` file. The command is:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `flyspell-mode`

Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can add hook to the `latex-mode`. You can add the following line into your `.emacs` file.

```
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)
```

I didn't test this, however, I think it should work. This will enable `flyspell-mode` whenever you enter the `latex-mode`.

Comment: And if you want to enable `flyspell-mode` for all text buffer, you can use the "meta hook" called `text-mode-hook` (as opposed to `prog-mode-hook` which is for buffer in a mode for development).

Comment: It's exactly what I want. Thank you